# jQueryUI menu with disabled menu items

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, menu, menuitem

I am using jQuery 1.10.2 and jQuery UI 1.10.3 to create a menu object with various menu items.

Standing on the [jQuery UI documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/menu/),

> Any menu item can be disabled by adding the **`ui-state-disabled`** class
>   to that element.

But unfortunately when disabling menu items the user can still click on the item and the click event still fire.

I have created a [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/AvEjOSUN/1/) to show the problem.

Any suggestion on how to solve this problem?
Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to know is *unbinding the event handler*.

Since you have written separate `click` event handler for **`li`**, it is wise to **`unbind`** its **`click`** event because **`ui-state-disabled`** is a CSS change which won't have effect in event handlers.

```
$('ul li a.mi3').addClass('ui-state-disabled').off('click');
```

[**JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/AvEjOSUN/4/)

Comment: Do I need to reattach back the click event in case I need it, or I can just write `.on('click')`?

Comment: @Lorenzo Yes, you can attach back the event using .on.  Its like switch ON/OFF.

Comment: I find it easier to only modify the click selector initially... $("#umDeleteRole:not(.ui-state-disabled)").click(function () {}); rather than removing the handler and readding it.